# Maven not downloading dependency's dependencies mentioned in the pom of that dependency library

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, transitive-dependency

So, I created two standalone spring boot libraries for my personal project. The following screenshot is of that project, which adds those two libraries as dependencies -
[Libraries in the main project, screenshot taken from intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpE1J.png)

Now, when I run `mvn clean install` on my main project, none of the dependency present in those libraries' pom.xml get downloaded.

As you can see there is that pom.xml file present in my library, but maven does not download those jjwt dependencies.
[Screenshot showing pom.xml and dependencies are there in one of the libraries, but none of those get downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRaca.png)

Can anyone please explain why maven is behaving like this? and, how can I force maven to download those transitive dependencies?

I have tried

- purging the local repository
- invalidate cache of intellij
- force update of maven dependencies

Comment: Show us your pom.xml.

Comment: Are there any warnings/errors shown in the output?